# .htaccess configuration, codeIgniter and facebook php sdk

Tags: php, .htaccess, facebook-php-sdk, codeigniter-2

I have to access `http://example.com/ABC/some-controller`. As per CodeIgniter you have to follow `http://example.com/ABC/index.php/some-controller`. Now I am using `.htaccess` to remove index.php. The problem I am facing is , if I use .htaccess file , my facebook login is not working because somehow  it is not picking up the GET variables set by FB.

My directory listing is as follows :

```
public_html
  ABC  (codeigniter folders inside this directory)
    applications 
    system
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

Now contents of my .htaccess to remove index.php from url :

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ABC
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ABC/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In config.php I have set the uri protocol to AUTO.
Thing to note here is , if I don't use `?` in last line (of .htaccess), it won't let me display page without index.php and throws error `No file specified` . If I use `?` then everything is fine , except , that my facebook login stops working when I add this in  .htaccess file, it keeps redirecting again and again . each time with a new code in get parameter. In my localserver everything is working fine. (In my localserver's .htaccess file I am not using `?` in last line, so I don't have to write index.php nor I have problem in fb login). I guess code of my fb login is correct as it is working on localhost, so not posting that code here. Please help me out to config my .htaccess for webserver so that it can use "get" parameters also. I am using **Arvix** web hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed by **switching** the web server from **Arvix** to **Amazon AWS**.

Answer (score 0):

> except , that my facebook login stops working when I add this in .htaccess file, it keeps redirecting again and again . each time with a new code in get parameter.

I think that's because your script never *receives* the `code` parameter.

Try using [the Flag `QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) in your RewriteRule, so that (additional) GET parameters send with the incoming request are passed on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, script is never receiving code parameter. Can you please tell me exact line I need to add in RewriteRule , I am bit confused from the link.Is this the line : 
RewriteRule /pages/(.+) /page.php?page=$1 [QSA] . What names should I gave here from my existing directory structure. Sorry I am bit confused.